# Are there posterior predictive check "point-values" in Bayesian modeling?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, stan

One standard for evaluating goodness-of-fit in Bayesian modeling is posterior predictive checks.  This means simultaneously visualizing the empirical distribution of the data along with the posterior predictive distribution, correct?  Do people use some more quantitative measure, like KL divergence between the empirical and posterior predictive distribution?

Some context:  I am working with hierarchical model in Stan.  My stakeholders want a quantity of goodness-of-fit, like R-squared.  I know one thing people do is cross-validation, but this KL-divergence idea seems to me to be something that people must have an opinion on, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: So you want a statistic (for example KL-divergence) to evaluate model fit similar to AIC, BIC, etc?

Comment: I don't think the KL-divergence between the distribution of $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n$ and a matrix of draws from posterior predictive distribution makes much sense. You might be thinking to collapse the matrix of draws from the posterior predictive distribution to the expected posterior predictive distribution for each observation, but comparing that to $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n$ is not Bayesian. On the other hand, a few of us threw together a note about a Bayesian analogue to R^2 at https://github.com/jgabry/bayes_R2 .